# A simple website with python using SimpleHTTPServer and SocketServer, how to only display the html file and not the whole directory?

Tags: python, networking, html

How do I only display `simplehttpwebsite_content.html` when I visit `localhost:8080`? So that I can't see my filetree, only the webpage. All these files are in the same directory btw.

simplehttpwebsite.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Handler)

server.serve_forever()
```

simplehttpwebsite_content.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simplehttpwebsite_style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    This is my first web page
  </body>
</html>
```

simplehttpwebsite_style.css

```
body{background-color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can extend `SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and override the `do_GET` method to replace `self.path` with `simplehttpwebpage_content.html` if `/` is requested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/simplehttpwebpage_content.html'
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = MyRequestHandler
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Handler)

server.serve_forever()
```

Since [`SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html#SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler) extends [`BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), you can read their documentations to figure what methods and instance variables are available and how you can manipulate them.

You can find the `path` variable mentioned in the documentation of [`BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler). You can find the `do_GET()` method mentioned in the documentation of [`SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html#SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler).

Here is some output from my shell to show what happens when I run this program and then I try to access `http://localhost:8080/`

```
susam@swift:~/so$ ls
simplehttpwebpage_content.html  simplehttpwebpage.py  simplehttpwebsite_style.css
susam@swift:~/so$ python simplehttpwebpage.py
swift - - [19/Apr/2012 09:10:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
swift - - [19/Apr/2012 09:10:26] "GET /simplehttpwebsite_style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Your `return` is not inside the function. Even when I place the return statement inside the function(method) I get a 404 Error.

Comment: Sorry Bentley4, that was a typo. I've fixed it now. Do you see any errors in the console where you are running `python simplehttpwebpage.py`? Note that `simplehttpwebpage_content.html` needs to be in the same directory in which you are running this script.

Comment: I wrote simplewebsite_content.html instead of simplewebpage_content.html. : ) . Works now.

Answer (score 12):

you should call your file `index.html`, that's the page that gets served automatically instead of listing the directory.

the other possibility would be to override the handlers `list_directory(self, path)` method.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted your answer. Your answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Susam Pal's answer, here is my implementation which allows the port to be set (just like when you run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`) and also serves up html pages when the file exists on the file server, without the .html extension.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import os.path
import sys

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):            
        possible_name = self.path.strip("/")+'.html'
        if self.path == '/':
            # default routing, instead of "index.html"
            self.path = '/simplehttpwebpage_content.html'
        elif os.path.isfile(possible_name):
            # extensionless page serving
            self.path = possible_name

        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = MyRequestHandler

port = 8000
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    try:
        p = int(sys.argv[1])
        port = p
    except ValueError:
        print "port value provided must be an integer"

print "serving on port {0}".format(port)
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', port), Handler)
server.serve_forever()
```